# Stable-Baslines3 Type Error in _predict w. custom environment & policy

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I'm in the process of integrating a custom environment and policy into Stable-Baselines3 (SB3). While setting up the `_predict` functionality, I encountered an issue. Although I can manually utilize the `_predict` functionality with a standard Python `dict`. I need to define the environment using `gym.spaces` when working with SB3. I suspect that SB3 uses the `gym.spaces` to do something internally. Consequently, I represent the observations from the environment using a standard Python dictionary and define the observation and action space using `gym.spaces`. However, when employing the SB3 Proximal Policy Optimization (PPO) algorithm, an error arises. It appears that PPO is passing the <class 'gymnasium.spaces.dict.Dict'> type instead of the actual `dict` observation. Perhaps I need to embed the observation into the observation space. However, I don't think this is possible. Should I utilize SB3 feature extractor in some fashion? Perhaps there is something that I have forgotten to define in order to ensure that the actual observation is used and not just the gym.space?

```
import numpy as np
import gymnasium as gym
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
from stable_baselines3.common.policies import BasePolicy


class CustomEnv(gym.Env):

    def __init__(self, nRows, nCols):
        super().__init__()

        # init
        self.nRows = nRows
        self.nCols = nCols
        self.iter = 0
        self.done = False
        self.truncated = False

        # action space
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(self.nRows * self.nCols)

        # observation space
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Dict({
            'layout': gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(self.nRows, self.nCols), dtype=np.uint8),
            'mask': gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(self.nRows * self.nCols,), dtype=np.uint8)
        })

        # actual observation
        self.observation = {'layout': np.zeros((self.nRows, self.nCols), dtype=np.uint8),
                            'mask': np.zeros(self.nRows * self.nCols, dtype=np.uint8)}

    def step(self, action):
        self.iter += 1
        reward = 0
        print("action: ", action)
        layout = self.observation["layout"].flatten()
        mask = self.observation["mask"]

        if layout[action] == 0:
            layout[action] = 1
            mask[action] = 1
            reward = 1
        else:
            reward = -1

        self.observation = {'layout': np.reshape(layout, (self.nRows, self.nCols)),
                            'mask': mask}

        if self.iter > self.nRows * self.nCols:
            self.done = True
            self.truncated = True

        info = {}

        return self.observation, reward, self.done, self.truncated, info

    def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
        # reset
        self.iter = 0
        self.done = False
        self.truncated = False

        self.observation = {'layout': np.zeros((self.nRows, self.nCols), dtype=np.uint8),
                            'mask': np.zeros(self.nRows * self.nCols, dtype=np.uint8)}
        info = {}

        return self.observation, info

    def render(self):
        pass

    def close(self):
        pass


class CustomPolicy(BasePolicy):
    def __init__(self, observation_space, action_space):
        super(CustomPolicy, self).__init__(observation_space, action_space)

        input_size = np.shape(observation_space["layout"])[0] * np.shape(observation_space["layout"])[1]
        output_size = action_space.n

        self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 5)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(5, output_size)

    def forward(self, obs, r=None, deterministic: bool = False, **kwargs):
        print(type(obs))
        x = torch.Tensor(obs["layout"].flatten())
        output = self.l1(x)
        output = self.relu(output)
        output = self.l2(output)
        return output

    def _predict(self, obs, deterministic: bool = False):
        # Forward pass through the network
        action_logits = self.forward(obs, deterministic=deterministic)
        if deterministic:
            # For deterministic action selection, take the action with maximum probability
            action = torch.argmax(action_logits)
        else:
            # For stochastic action selection, sample from the action distribution
            action_probs = F.softmax(action_logits, dim=0)
            action_dist = torch.distributions.Categorical(probs=action_probs)
            action = action_dist.sample()
        return action, None  # Don't need log-prob.


# Create an instance of your custom environment
env = CustomEnv(3, 3)
custom_policy = CustomPolicy(env.observation_space, env.action_space)

# Running a small test
action = env.action_space.sample()
observation, reward, done, truncated, _ = env.step(action)

action, _ = custom_policy._predict(observation, False)
print(action)

action, _ = custom_policy._predict(observation, True)
print(action)

# train PPO with your custom environment and custom policy
model = PPO(policy=custom_policy, env=env, verbose=1).model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)

# eval
mean_reward, std_reward = evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=10)
print(f"Mean reward: {mean_reward} +/- {std_reward}")


-------------THE ERROR-------------------
x = torch.Tensor(obs["layout"].flatten())
AttributeError: 'Box' object has no attribute flatten
```